# python twisted and multiprocessing

Tags: python, twisted, multiprocessing

How can I fork (via Process wrapping) and have twisted completely reset in the new process.
I have to spawn a new process from a process with a lot of reactor but I need to chage reactors (in the new process) removing something and adding something else.

For example I need a glib2reactor both in parent and in child....but twisted notifies to me that reactor has been already installed (after fork). Fork copies parent memory to the child with every twisted-reactors..How can I "reset" twisted in the child?

Thank you for your help,

Dudda

Answer (score 0):

`os.fork()` clones the current process, returning the process id of the child to the parent and 0 to the child.

```
if os.fork():
    "parent"
else:
    "child"
```

If you use `os.system()` or the [`subprocesses`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module you get a fresh-new process.

You can use a fork, `&`, in your `os.system()` command to avoid blocking.

```
error = os.system('ls &')
```

[`os.execv`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.execv) and friends replace the current process with the target command.

Answer (score 0):

Twisted supports launching arbitrary child processes (including processes using Twisted) via `twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorProcess`.  See [the process howto](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html) for details of how to use it.